# Google Map Centers at top left corner

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been looking at many different examples, problems, and other things regarding this and I can't seem to find anything, so i'll finally ask a question.

The map I have does not center the marker and doesn't even display it. The point it the very top left corner. See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK1g0.png

I have a tab system for contact information. When someone clicks a tab, the map and info slides down and shows up the proper marker (4 separate maps), however I can't get the first one to work so I can't copy/paste it.

Here is my code:

Script:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.3535727, -83.0591444);
var options = {  
      zoom: 14,  
      center: latlng,  
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('detroit_map'), options);
marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({  
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.3535727, -83.0591444),
            map: map
          }); 
map.setCenter(latlng);
```

Html:

```
<div id="detroit_map" style="width:270px;height:170px;"></div>
```

P.S, I get no errors in chrome developer tools.

It's hopefully something really simple that I overlooked.

Thanks

**Found the answer for future viewers**:

Turns out, my tabs causing the display between block, and none were making my map load weird. I made an initialize function for each, and called setTimout('functionName', 1000); to call the maps to load.

I changed my map code a little bit, but everything can we found on w3schools under their tutorial.

Comment: Your script above has an error; remove the trailing comma after ROADMAP to fix

Comment: Thank you for adding your own answer, it helped me solve a similar problem. Calling the map init function, after changing display to "block", was the solution for me.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize the map after the tab is clicked. This also works for the iframe google map, when used inside a tab.

Answer (score 2):

Tell your map to resize..

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

map is the map instance that is returned by

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Comment: an you provide a link or a jsfiddle that exhibits the issue?

Comment: I figured it out and added the answer to my question, thanks though.

Comment: I was initializing my map in a hidden div. I guess this caused the map to have no size. Then when it was displayed, center was in the top left because of no size. Calling resize before setCenter works. Thank you!